# Can't submit an advanced certificate request to CA

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate-authority, scom

I'm trying to submit an advanced certificat request to the CA trought Certificate Enrolment URL (http://my-ca-srv/certsrv) but I can't get the form in wich I'll fill information about target server.

Instead I get the a form that helps me to submit a saved request to the CA by pasting a base-64-encoded CMC certificate request...

Can you please suggest me any solution.

Cordially.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved now. the problem was caused by internet browser updates. I access to CA certificate Enrolment Web from an old version of my browser and it works.

Another alternative is to use the management console to generate the request (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10377.create-a-certificate-request-using-microsoft-management-console-mmc.aspx)